# A right triangle drawn inside another right triangle

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

$\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $AB=6$. A line $BX$ is drawn from vertex $B$ to leg $AC$, so that $AX=3$. Then a line $XY$ is drawn to the hypotenuse, forming a right triangle, with $XY=2$. How do you find $BC$?

I tried looking for similar triangles, applying the Pythagorean theorem to the various right triangles, but can't seem to figure it out.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure XY isn't meant to form a right angle with AB? I haven't solved this problem, but it seems much more common to have a right angle with the hypotenuse judging from other problems I've seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $BC = x$

Let $XC = y$

Let $BY = z$..

$x^2 + y^2 = BX^2$

$BX^2 +4 = x^2 + y^2 + 4 = z^2$

$x^2 + (3+y)^2 = 36$

$x^2 + y^2 + 6y + 9 = 36$

$x^2 + y^2 =BX^2 = 27-6y$

Note $\angle YXA \cong \angle XBC$ so by law of cosines

$2\cos YXA =\frac {y^2-x^2 - BX^2}{x\cdot BX}=\frac {(6-z)^2-2^2-3^2}{2\cdot 3}$.

And that's enough to solve.

$2\cos YXA =\frac {y^2-x^2 - BX^2}{x\cdot BX}=-\frac {2x^2}{x(x^2+y^2)}=-\frac {2x}{x^2 + y^2}$

And $2\cos YXA = \frac {(6-z)^2-2^2-3^2}{2\cdot 3}=\frac {23-12z + z^2}6$

So we have three equations and thre unknowns

$x^2 +y^2 = z^2-4$

$x^2 + y^2 = 27-6y$

$-\frac {2x}{x^2 + y^2}=\frac {23-12z + z^2}6$

Nasty but doable.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to place the diagram on a coordinate plane with $B$ at the origin, and let $\angle ABC = \theta$, so that $$\begin{align}
A &= (6 \cos \theta, 6 \sin \theta), \\ 
C &= (6 \cos \theta, 0), \\ 
X &= (6 \cos \theta, 6 \sin \theta - 3), \\
Y &= (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta),
\end{align}$$
where $0 < r < 6$.  Then the simultaneous conditions $XY \perp BX$ and $XY = 2$ yield the system in $r, \theta$
$$\begin{align}
r^2 - 12r + 45 + 6(r - 6) \sin \theta &= 4, \\
6r - 45 - 3(r-12) \sin \theta & = 0.
\end{align}$$
This leads to a cubic polynomial in $r$, from which we can also obtain $BC = 6 \cos \theta$.  But a closed form solution is lengthy and not particularly nice.

Comment: Another approach with $C$ as the origin and $A=(0,a)$ leads to [$1044 - 120a - 49a^2 + 6a^3=0$](https://tio.run/##LcixCsMgEIDh3Scx9iw2gSxy7xC6hgxnKjRDOhR7KOKz25pm@n@@ncLT7xS2lWp1jNmBKZZ@Y4CKTYxBOb7Imw6dIraRMbaK6b29wizu/vFZ/ZwlsXbcXc8ijmoEGVlTw38RBzUcmE5MDXvVg3SsY8N0FNEUyAQOAsSyiKXWLw), then $BC=\sqrt{36-a^2}$.

Comment: yes, but what is a?

Comment: There's only one value of $a$ possible. Can you see why?